# Page numbering problem in list of contents with "abstract"

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am having a problem with numbering my pages. I want the numbers to start after the abstract, so I put the page numbering after it. It works fine for the pages itself, this means the abstract does not have a page number, and chapter one which is the next page has page 1, which is exactly what I want. Unfortunately there is a problem in the list of contents, which shows the page number 2 for my abstract. How can I hide this single number?
[image]

Comment: So, you don't want the page number for the abstract on the table of contents? So, why to insert it there?

Comment: Unfortunately the definition of task demands it. And it also works for the pages, just not for the table of contents.

Comment: I guess that it is almost impossible to delete only one page number from table of contents, at least automatically.

Comment: I am also thankful for any hint to delete the page number manually.

Comment: Which class do you use?

Comment: a mechanism is described in the ams author faq to suppress a toc entry and replace it with another one, that may be useful; see 
http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238 .  whether or not it is helpful will probably depend on what document class you are using; if it *is* useful, please say so, and i will make an answer of this information.

Comment: Thanks barbarabeeton, I will try this.
@Bernard I am using apalike.

Answer (score 1):

### Manual solution

Since you are not using dots before the page numbers, you can edit the `toc` file and delete the page number leaving the braces empty `{}`.

Then, save it and **compile only once**.

This will remove the page number but will update the `toc` file so that if you compile again, the page number comes back.

Do this just before to print you document or just before to send it to someone.

```
\contentsline {section}{Abstract}{}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}title}{1}
```

[image]